# What's the difference between minmax() and clamp() in CSS?

Tags: css, grid, minmax

Both CSS functions clamp the value between an upper and lower bound.

The only difference that I know is that minmax() can only be used in CSS grid.

Comment: Did you do some research on this ? quick look in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) would tell you that clamp allows a middle value, minmax doesn't

Comment: I would say, they are completely different. The comparaison doesn't apply

Answer (score 6):

[minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) may only be used in Grid and picks between two (2) parameters.

[clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) can be used anywhere in CSS and picks between three (3) parameters: minimum, preferred, and maximum, selecting the middle (*preferred*) parameter when possible.

Answer (score 2):

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()):

> `clamp()` enables selecting a middle value within a range of values between a defined minimum and maximum. It takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value, and a maximum allowed value.

`minmax()` only accepts the two extreme values, plus the difference that you already mentioned.